# How to declare an unsigned long type in java?

Tags: unsigned-integer

I need my program to run with big, natural numbers and zero. The program itself is not important to this question, or at least I think it is not. I looked up which primitiv data type would suite my aim best and I found the unsigned long.

Accroding to the webisite, unsined longs are supported from java 8 and onwarts. However, it does not say how to declare a variable as an unsigned long. 
By googling, I find pages complaining about the lack of unsigned data types compared to C++ (from where I now the principe of unsigned primitiv types).

So my question is, how to declare an unsigned long type in java?

The aim of the big number is to make the implementation slower. The reason therefore is to compare two methods, doing the same job. It is an university asignment, so I am not interested in how much sense this makes. 
If unasigned types do not work in java or only very inconvienently, which primitiv data type allows the usage of the highest positiv and whole numbers? Is long or double suited better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can.
You could however try [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: OK, then I have to use something else. Would you say that long or double allows bigger, positiv, whole numbers?

Comment: I think a long will hold 2^63-1 positive values. I think a double will hold 2^52 positive values before it loses integral resolution.